# SEL as IBOutlet in iOS

Tags: ios, interface-builder

How do I add an action to a custom view?  Similar to how UIButtons have an action I can connect in Inteface Builder.  I can't use a SEL like below because it's not an object, what do I use?

```
 @property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet SEL action;
```

Comment: I use (nonatomic, assign) when using integers, have you tried that?

Comment: not sure for an IBOutlet though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make your custom object a subclass of UIControl (which is a subclass of UIView). Then you get all the target/action methods... if you are doing this in code the one to explore will be

```
– addTarget:action:forControlEvents:
```

If you make a custom UIControl object, then you can drag out a custom view in the storyboard and set it's custom class to your customControl. Then you can drag out IBAction links to your viewController just as if it were a button.

Here is how to make one in code...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIControl* customControl = [[UIControl alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 200)];
    customControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [customControl addTarget:self 
                      action:@selector(customAction:) 
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:customControl];
}

- (void)customAction:(id)sender
{
    NSLog (@"touched");
}
```

Comment: It's a UITextField and action is already there from the UIControl.  Just didn't bother to look.  Assumed I had to add it for a text field.

Comment: Scratch that,  Action was for segues.

Comment: Are you adding your custom view to a viewController using the storyboard?

Comment: I see the controls in IB now.  Sorry, focusing on too many things at once.